# Show that $3281$ is a strong pseudoprime to base $3$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, pseudoprimes

> How can I show that $3281$ is a strong pseudoprime to base $3$?

My attempt: $3^d≡1$ mod $3281$, which is true for $d=16k$ and $3281=17\cdot193$. Hence $3281$ is a strong pseudoprime to base $3$.

Does this solution confirm to the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime ?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Show that 3281 is a strong pseudoprime to base 3

Comment: No, you have to begin with $3281=2^4\cdot 205+1$ and you have to show that either you have $3^{205}\equiv 1\mod 3281$ or $3^{205\cdot 2^t}\equiv -1\mod 3281$ for some non-integer $t$

Comment: You can show $3^{1640}\equiv -1\mod 3281$ by reducing the exponent modulo $16$ (because you already know $3^{16}\equiv 1\mod 3281$) , so you only need $3^8\equiv -1\mod 3281$ and , as you mentioned, that $3281$ is not prime.

Comment: I neither understand the downvote nor the closevote. The author showed what she tried and the question is clear.

Comment: Thank you so much so all I would need to do was show $3^{205}$≡ 1 mod $3281$ which I dont believe works when plugged into a calculator, but for the second option it does. If you have time would you be able to explain the reduction you did possibly a bit further that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Elena No problem : Suppose, you have $n=16j+k$ and $a^{16} \equiv 1\mod N$ , then $$a^n=a^{16j+k}=(a^{16})^j\cdot a^k\equiv 1^j\cdot a^k=a^k\mod N$$

Comment: @Elena In fact, $3^{205}\equiv 1\mod 3281$ does not hold. This would imply $3^{1640}\equiv 1\mod 3281$, which is apparently not the case. You can also see this by reducing $205$ mod $16$ to get $3^{13}\ne 1\mod 3281$

Comment: Thank you so so much, one more thing your second bit is the only bit that needs to be proven if im not mistaken. $3^{16}$ $≡$ mod $3281$

Comment: @Elena In fact , this and that $3281$ is composite is sufficient here. Start with $3^4=81$. Squaring gives $3^8\equiv -1\mod 3281$ , which is already enough to show $3^{1640}\equiv -1\mod 3281$ because of $$3^{1640}=(3^8)^{205}\equiv (-1)^{205}=-1\mod 3281$$ Using this, you do not even need $3^{16}\equiv 1\mod 3281$